# SQL Server 2012 query string containing slash

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, full-text-search

I've looked all over the internet and stackoverflow for an answer to this question, but can't seem to find anything that answers it so here goes...

Is there anything special that needs to be done to a forward slash (/) for them to be included in search queries?

Scenario:  I have a query that contains a string being searched for that includes a forward slash.  The search term is a dimension of a particular item so it must contain the slash to indicate a fraction.  I've tried escaping it with a backslash, but that doesn't work.  The query is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM ITEMDATA WHERE CONTAINS(dimensions, '3/8')
```

This query returns 0 results.

Example of data to be searched on:

> •Pitch: 3/8"
>   •Gauge: .050

I also need to get the double quote in the search phrase to specify units, but that's another problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm afraid that SQL server full text only index letters. Not sure if 2012 changed that.

Answer (score 1):

As the following demonstrates, you can use "/" in a `LIKE` expression without any tricks:

```
create table foo(a int, b varchar(32))
go

insert into foo select 1, 'for 3/8 inch';
go

select * from foo where b like '%3/8%';
go
```

This will result in the single row being found.

Answer (score 0):

If we need to search in sql table column with a particular string, we need to use LIKE command, so that we can use it like in various ways.
1. Returns results  having dimensions column value contains the string 3/8

```
'SELECT * FROM ITEMDATA WHERE dimensions LIKE '%3/8%';`
```

2. Returns results  having dimensions column value strictly starts with the string 3/8

`SELECT * FROM ITEMDATA WHERE dimensions LIKE '3/8%';`

3. Returns results  having dimensions column value strictly ends with the string 3/8.

`SELECT * FROM ITEMDATA WHERE dimensions LIKE '3/8%';`

Answer (score 0):

Disable STOPLIST for full-text:

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON table SET STOPLIST OFF
```

and try

```
SELECT * FROM ITEMDATA WHERE CONTAINS (dimensions, '"3/8*"')
```